# Globally suppressing a warning type in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, suppress-warnings

I have a Java application that I work on using Eclipse.  I have hundreds of warnings that are all due to things like this:

`ArrayList< SomeType > list = new ArrayList();`

generating a warning that ArrayList is a raw type since I haven't included the type specifier when allocating the ArrayList itself.  Is there a way to suppress this warning globally in Eclipse, rather than adding a @SuppressWarning annotation?

I'm concerned that I'm missing a warning that may be more valuable because of all these raw type ones.

Comment: Why don't you fix the raw type warnings?

Comment: Because I know that I am not interested in being warned about that.  I rarely explicitly type the allocated generic, since it's a compile-time restriction only IIRC.  I just don't want the abundance of warnings like that masking ones I'm actually concerned about.

Comment: Well, you should use raw types where possible. From the spec: `The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can change the settings by navigating -

```
project properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Generics types
```

Enable the - Enable project specific settings

Change warning to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this -

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
ArrayList< SomeType > list = new ArrayList();
```

warning will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `-Xlint:unchecked` command line option but that would be the same as `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` which btw can be put on individual assignments like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
ArrayList< SomeType > list = new ArrayList();
```

However, I strongly recommend to fix those warnings where possible and only suppress them in specific cases you are sure about.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a directory containing a large number of generated files.  For that case, warnings can be switched off per directory.  In the package exploreer, right click on the directory, then choose

```
Properties -> Java Compiler -> Ignore optional compile problems
```

Note that this switches off other warnings as well - but for generated code, these have to be fixed by changing the generator anyway.